# HashWithIndifferentAccess doesn't work with % format operator in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Ruby string's method `%` allows to substitute name placeholders with the values of the given hash: `"Hello %{name}" % {name: "World"}` will result with `"Hello World"`.

The problem is that it doesn't work with `HashWithIndifferentAccess` arguments. In Rails 5 this code would raise an exception:

```
2.3.8 :001 > "%{a}" % {"a" => 1}.with_indifferent_access
KeyError: key{a} not found
    from (irb):1:in `%'
    from (irb):1
```

It's also interesting that the same code works fine in Rails 4 but not in Rails 5

Is there a way to fix it (maybe some monkey-patching of `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`) and understand why the behavior of `%` (and `sprintf` too) has changed?

Comment: `with_indifferent_access` method always returns hash with string keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly because of the changes introduced to `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` through the different releases as long as Rails has been evolving and to the [`default`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activesupport/lib/active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb#L219) method (don't confuse with Hash#default).

If you see in the Rails 4 version of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess the default method looks like:

```
def default(key = nil)
  if key.is_a?(Symbol) && include?(key = key.to_s)
    self[key]
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Which is clearly receiving a key when is invoked, checking its type and if is included within the hash (self) as one of its keys, returns its value, otherwise invokes super.

And in newer versions (newer because your example doesn't work in Rails 4+ versions) it looks like:

```
def default(*args)
  super(*args.map { |arg| convert_key(arg) })
end

def convert_key(key) # :doc:
  key.kind_of?(Symbol) ? key.to_s : key
end
```

Which attempts to return every element from the arguments passed to default when being invoked to String if it's a symbol or return the same element.

This in your example would return nil for `default`, which explains the KeyError error you're getting.

The error or difference in the behavior isn't `%` but in the changes introduced.

Comment: `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess#default` is same as `Hash#default`. Atleast, this is what the docs say.
Going by the docs, the recent(Rails 4+ versions) definition of `default` method looks correct.

Comment: I don't understand your point. What's does "correct" mean in this case?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Thank you for the answer. But I don't understand why does it `%` use `default` instead of directly accessing the values using `[]` method?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that. `%` doesn't use `default`, default is checked when invoking `with_indifferent_access` on a Hash.

Comment: I meant that the `default` method should return only the default value for that key and not the value for that key in the hash. Having that said, `default` method should only call `super` and not `self`.